# Zope Conflict Errors

Tags: zope, zodb

My site's zope log reports a number of conflict errors. Average of 120 per day of which 2-3 are unresolved. I've come across many articles on why conflict errors occur but nothing has been clear.

Most of these conflict errors occur on pages which run select queries on MySQL database.
It is said that the number of conflict errors rise with an increase in concurrency of http requests because one ZODB object is created and the other tries to write to it.
(I could not understand why and how ZODB objects are modified. Can anyone explain this ?)

But even when there is only one user using it, there are conflict errors raised. This generally happens when the website is accessed for the first time after an overnight restart of Zope.

What I've noticed that during some instances, trying to load a page which involves running a select query against a table raises a conflict error if the table is modified at the same time because of some other activity on the website.

All of this has to do with the ZODB object stuff. It should be storing the data from the table as an object or something. The original data is changed and hence the conflict. Am I correct ?

The website uses Zope 2.12.19 with Zope's built-in session manager and Python 2.6.8

A sample of the log file is below:

```
2014-03-26T12:31:27 INFO ZPublisher.Conflict ConflictError at /VirtualHostBase/https/xyz.com:443/ESA/VirtualHostRoot/test: database conflict error (oid 0x04a6, class BTrees.OOBTree.OOBTree, serial this txn started with 0x03a5bd4f6e81a2bb 2014-03-26 12:31:25.899935, serial currently committed 0x03a5bd4f73e1e833 2014-03-26 1`2:31:27.159949) (115 conflicts (3 unresolved) since startup at Wed Mar 26 00:01:06 2014)
```

Comment: You are using sessions; sessions write to the ZODB database as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Less Conflicting Session Manager for Zope 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10187813/less-conflicting-session-manager-for-zope-2)

Comment: Thanks Martijn.. I've come across your post wherein you suggested Beaker. I will implement it soon. But wanted to understand what causes the conflict errors. So, for example, if 2-3 conflict errors occur on a page with a gap of 2 secs, you mean that the session object of both the pages is trying to write to ZODB ? What kind of information session stores in ZODB ?

Comment: Creating a session needs to alter a BTree to store the session id and buckets. Adding information to a session causes writes as well. Anything you store in the session, is stored in the ZODB, the browser holds a session id only.

Comment: The default number of threads are 4 isn't it ? Can the ZODB be written to simultaneously by all the four or is it just one at at time ?

Comment: Only one thread can write at a time; the ZODB handles conflicts (trying to alter the same persistent record) by raising an exception, and Zope handles conflicts by retrying the whole request (restart the transaction).

Comment: Thanks Martijn. It is sort of clear now. BTW, when you say "by raising an exception" do you mean a ConflictError in the log ?

Comment: No, the ZODB raises an exception for every conflict. Zope catches these and retries the transaction. Zope then does write statistics on the outcome of such retries in the log.

Comment: So, ZODB should raise lot of exceptions when there is high concurrency. This would mean if there are 20 requests which implies min. of 20 session objects (assuming that each uses a session) trying to write to ZODB. Does this not slow down the website ?

Comment: It does, which is why I recommend you don't use the built-in session manager and go for something more scalable instead.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Does adding Beaker involve code changes ? I ask this because the default session data manager has the "Transient Object Container Path" and "Place SESSION in REQUEST object as" variables with the corresponding values as "/temp_folder/session_data" and "SESSION". How can you enter this information using Beaker.

Comment: You'll have to read the documentation for the add-on.

Comment: Yes.. I've gone through it. Saving in session for example using Beaker is different from how it is done in general. Correct me if I'm wrong here but that is what the docs seem to say. Hence I asked if code changes are required?

Comment: The application code doesn't change; swapping out the session manager only changes how you configure the manager.